# How to read a csv file that has points as thousand separator on excel

Tags: excel

So, I've got that huge csv file that contains numbers that use "." as number separators (I guess this is how they roll in germany). Some of them are negative numbers.
I have to check that the sum is a certain amount just to be sure they sent me the correct data. When I just replace the dots with nothing I get an incorrect total (close to the total they sent me, but still incorrect). And as I can't review the whole file to find if there is something wrong somewhere, I can't be certain that the issue lies with the data or with something I didn't expect (like a line that would use "." as a decimal separator for example, but maybe there are more exotic cases that I could quite not imagine)

I'm pretty sure there must be a way to make excel understand that "." is a thousand separator, but so far I didn't manage to make that custom format understand what I'm trying to say.
Well this is actually half-true, I can make him understand that it should write 1.000.000 instead of 1000000 but I can't make him understand that it should read 1.000.000 as 1000000.
I also tried my luck at changing the separator in File > Options > Advanced > Use system separator, but it doesn't seem to work (like at all, when I change it, nothing changes, maybe this feature is bugged)

NB : I'm french and my default separator is a space. Though I could change the language to english, I can't change it to german because the package is not installed and I can't install anything on my working computer (cause "securtity and blahblahblah").

Thank you for your kind help.
Regards.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Do not open the CSV file directly. Open a blank file and then import the CSV file as text. In the wizard, there is a step where you can click on *Advanced options* and there specify the decimal separator char and the thousands separator char. https://www.howtogeek.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/03/advanced-options.png

Comment: Thanks. This worked great. 
Alternatively I fixed my issue with the separator options. I misunderstood how you had to use it. You actually need to uncheck the box for it to work, otherwise it will use the default parameters (whatever that means).